# calling multiple methods in oncreate method in android

Tags: java, android

I have multiple methods to be called when activity is started. I have added those methods in the oncreate method. The problem is when the activity is started some methods are called some or not called. How do i call all the methods when the activity is started.

My code is

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
     RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

     client.post("http://localhost/website/getdbrowcount.php",params ,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()
     {

          public void onSuccess(String response) 
          {
              try
              {
                 Log.d("home", "success"); 
                 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                 Log.d("home", obj.toString());
                System.out.println(obj.get("count"));      

                syncDB();
                sync();
                subsync();
                syncfeature();
                syncelec();
                syncconnector();
                synccontrols();
                synckeypad();
                syncmech();
                syncorder();
                syncpower();
              }

              catch (JSONException e) 
              {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
             }
          }

          public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error,String content) 
          {
              if(statusCode == 404)
              {
                update.setText("The update has been cancelled. Please update via Settings to work"
                            + " with latest Sonetonix product data");
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  btn1.setEnabled(true);
                  btn1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
              }
              else if(statusCode == 500)
              {
                update.setText("The update has been cancelled. Please update via Settings to work"
                            + " with latest Sonetonix product data");
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  btn1.setEnabled(true);
                  btn1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
              }
              else
              {
                update.setText("The update has been cancelled. Please update via Settings to work"
                            + " with latest Sonetonix product data");
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  btn1.setEnabled(true);
                  btn1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
              }
              Log.d("home", "failure");
          }
     });       
}
```

In the code when OnSuccess the methods has to be called but only syncDB(),sync() is called and rest are not called . What change should i make in the code to resolve this issue.

Please help

Comment: Check for exception in sync method. Which must be terminating the execution and catching the exception.

Comment: but sometimes syncpower,syncfeatures,synccontrols called along with that but others are not getting called

Answer (score 0):

It is because in the `sync()` method or possibly at the start of the `subsync()` method your program is throwing an error. Because of the try/catch block, you are allowing the program to continue.

Check the method for an error and fix that.

Comment: sometimes other methods are also called.subsync is not called sometimes

Comment: Could be a connection issue. Just check the stackTrace to see what's causing the issue. I can't tell you without knowing whats inside the methods

Comment: in the method iam calling asynchronous client and onsuccess i am calling the method  update(response)

Comment: Did you check the StackTrace. That will tell you what you need to know

Comment: ya i checked the stacktrace but there are no errors nor exception